# Flask-SQLAlchemy -- One model having two different relationships

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I have three models: Role, User, and Post. Role -> User is one to many, and User -> Post is one to many. When I just had User and Post, everything worked. However, my website will need varying degrees of authorization.

```py
class Role(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    users = db.relationship('User', backref='role', lazy=True)


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('role.id'), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
```

Here is the error message I get:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) 
no such column: user.role_id
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to explicitly define the `role_id` field - the relationship defined in `Role` (and the `backref` parameter you specified) has already created a backwards relationship on `User` objects for you. (The SQLAlchemy [documentation around backrefs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/backref.html#relationships-backref) may be helpful to you.)

As such, if you have an instantiated `User` object `u`, you should be able to get details about the user's role via `u.role` (which will give you a `Role` instance) and the ID of the role as `u.role.id`.

Thus, your full set of model definitions only needs to look like this:

```
class Role(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    users = db.relationship('User', backref='role', lazy=True)


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

If you do this, then for a `Post` object `p`, you can get the id of the role of the author of the post as `p.author.role.id` (for example).

Comment: Cool! okay, but then why would `user_id` in the `Post` model work before?

Comment: Honestly? Not sure off the top of my head why it worked for the one case and not the other, but I'm also not going to waste too much time trying to figure it out since there's a more standard and expected way of accomplishing what you're trying to do. :)

Comment: (That said - if you're adding new fields to your models, are you either wiping your database in between or otherwise having SQLAlchemy update its schema? It's possible that the error you're getting was because the actual table in the database still had the schema from when you originally created the User model and didn't have a Role model.)

Comment: So I actually tried updating it, and it added the Role model, but it still said the user_role.id column wasnt found.... weird. I appreciate the help though, I was following this series online and since I am not good at this stuff, was following his tutorial verbatim. I finished it now, and got a book that goes more in depth, so I am really trying to understand how things work because the syntax keeps changing.

Comment: So I took out what you said to, but ended up getting `sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Role.users - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.` Any thoughts?